# A hypercube with side length 1 in d dimensions is defined to be the set of points

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, linear-regression

**The Question**: A hypercube with side length 1 in d dimensions is defined to be the set of points (x1, x2, ..., xd) such that  for all j = 1, 2, ..., d. The boundary of the hypercube is defined to be the set of all points such that there exists a j for which  or  (namely, the boundary is the set of all points that have at least one dimension in the most extreme 10% of possible values). What proportion of the points in a hypercube of dimension 50 are in the boundary? (hint: you may want to calculate the volume of the non-boundary region)

**An Aside:** I found this question when going through edX's Statistical Learning Course, Section2.2 by Stanford University.

**Problem:** I don't understand what's going on in the question, there also doesn't seem to be a detailed explanation or some other resource I can refer to. I am also unable to wrap my head around a cube with d dimensions.

**What I'm Looking for:** if someone could explain me this question in utmost detail possible assuming I have little to no knowledge of what is being talked about.

**What I Know:** Vectors and Matrices.